# jquery accordion ui styling on first expandable table but not on the other

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I don't do much programming and I have been playing around with jquery UI components to hopefully incorporate some of them into our HTML output. I am currently trying to see how accordion works in a table and have pieced together some code. I like the styling that jquery provides but I can only get styling to work for the first row of the first table. Please help!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Accordion - Collapse content</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script>
   $(function() {
      $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
         collapsible: true
   });
   var $activity = $('.activity');
   $activity.find("tr").not('.accordion').hide();
   $activity.find("tr").eq(0).show();

   $activity.find(".accordion").click(function(){
      $activity.find('.accordion').not(this).siblings().fadeOut(500);
      $(this).siblings().fadeToggle(500);
   }).eq(0).trigger('click');
   });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table class="activity">
   <tbody>
        <tr id="accordion" class="accordion">
          <td colspan="3">This is the header</td>
        </tr>
  <tr id="accordion">
    <td>Activity</td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>Role</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="accordion">
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
<table class="activity">
<tbody>
    <tr id="accordion" class="accordion">
    <td colspan="3">This is the header</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Activity</td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>Role</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id must be unique, in your case you are assigning `accordion` id to more than one element.

Use class `accordion` instead, and remove accordion as id:

```
$(function () {
    $(".accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true
    });
    var $activity = $('.activity');
    $activity.find("tr").not('.accordion').hide();
    $activity.find("tr").eq(0).show();

    $activity.find(".accordion").click(function () {
        $activity.find('.accordion').not(this).siblings().fadeOut(500);
        $(this).siblings().fadeToggle(500);
    }).eq(0).trigger('click');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/edqPG/

Comment: Thanks that worked! How do I get it to use the styling in the rows below the heading?

Comment: Can you expand a bit, I don't understand your second question

Comment: The styling was applied to the header rows but when you click to expand the rows, the styling isn't applied to the rows underneath it. Sorry if these questions are dumb I am just fumbling around with it and don't have much experience.

Answer (score 0):

In the Jquery UI source [here](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) the id "accordion" applies to the whole div. If you want to be able to do that with tables, you should apply your id to the`<table>` instead of the `<tr>`